# Bad file descriptor

Tags: c, file, unix, file-descriptor

I'm learning about file descriptors and I wrote this code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int fdrd, fdwr, fdwt;
char c;

main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if((fdwt = open("output", O_CREAT, 0777)) == -1) {
        perror("Error opening the file:");
        exit(1);
    }

    char c = 'x';

    if(write(fdwt, &c, 1) == -1) {
        perror("Error writing the file:");
    }

    close(fdwt);
    exit(0);

}
```

, but I'm getting: `Error writing the file:: Bad file descriptor`

I don't know what could be wrong, since this is a very simple example.

Comment: What is the val of fdwt on return from open( )? It should be a small integer, like less than 5. In fact, because no other fds are open in this code, it should be 3 (i.e., STDERR + 1).

Comment: Incidentally, your code has several problematic bits. Those variables don't need to be global (few ever do), you should declare them in `main`. You also declare `c` twice, you don't need the `char` in `char c` the second time. At the same time, the second declaration of `c` in the middle of the function is only valid in C99, but you declare `main` without a return type -- which is invalid in C99, which eliminates the "implicit int" rule that was present in C89 and earlier versions of C. Most compilers should issue warnings for that, some will throw an error and refuse to compile.

Answer (score 31):

Try this:

```
open("output", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0777)
```

Comment: Wow! So fast! :) That worked! Now I have to find out why! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Lucy - It gave you a file descriptor, so the open didn't fail ... but the descriptor was not valid for writing.

Comment: Could you explain why O_WRONLY is required, and where 0777 comes from?

Comment: 0777 is honestly a bad idea from a security perspective (but it's what the OP already had). The "other" permissions shouldn't contain write without a _very_ good reason, nor should random data files be created with execute.

Answer (score 10):

I think `O_CREAT` alone is not enough. Try adding `O_WRONLY` as flag to the open command.

Answer (score 10):

According to the open(2) man page:

> The argument flags must include one of the following access modes: O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, or O_RDWR.

So yes, as suggested by others, please change your `open` to `open("output", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0777));`. Use `O_RDWR` if you need to read from the file. You may also want `O_TRUNC` -- see the man page for details.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I used the `S_IRUSR` constant, which then, combined with `O_CREAT` created a file that can't be written to.
So first run was OK, but on the second run I got the *Bad file descriptor* error message.

Using `S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR` solved the problem.
Of course the badly created files have to be deleted.

```
int outfd = open("output.ppm", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```