# What could cause "bad file descriptor" in multithreaded environment?

Tags: c++, c, linux, posix, file-descriptor

<sub>This question is somehow similar to [Bad file descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245477/bad-file-descriptor) but it's not the same at all. I know this is "bad question" ("too localized" maybe), but I can't figure it out and I'm now out of any ideas.</sub>

---

## Introduction

I have a manager thread, that starts 75 other threads. Each of these threads do a lot of things, so I'll describe only the relevant ones.

**Please note**: if I start only a few threads - for example 3 or 5, or 10, this error does not appear! This makes me think, that this is some multithreading issue, but it doesn't seem to be such.. And you'll see why in the next sections.

So, in the following 2 cases, **SOMETIMES** I receive this error `Bad file descriptor`:

---

## case 1

The error appears in `TinyXML`

There's an xml file, that's needed by all threads. All of these threads use `TinyXML` to parse the file. ALL of these threads use this file **READ-ONLY!** (I know this can be optimized, but whatever).

So, the code, that causes the `Bad file descriptor` error is this:

```
// ...
// NOTE: this is LOCAL, other threads do NOT have access to it
TiXmlDocument   doc;
doc.LoadFile( filename );

// and here's the LoadFile:
bool TiXmlDocument::LoadFile( const char* _filename, TiXmlEncoding encoding )
{
    //...
    FILE* file = fopen( value.c_str (), "rb" ); 
    if ( file )
    {
        // this IS executed, so file is NOT NULL for sure
        bool result = LoadFile( file, encoding );
        //...
    }
    //...
}

bool TiXmlDocument::LoadFile( FILE* file, TiXmlEncoding encoding )
{
    // ...
    long length = 0;
    fseek( file, 0, SEEK_END );
    // from the code above, we are SURE that file is NOT NULL, it's valid, but
    length = ftell( file ); // RETURNS -1 with errno: 9 (BAD FILE DESCRIPTOR)
    // how is this possible, as "file" is not NULL and it appears to be valid?
    // ...
}
```

---

## case 2

This is a bit more complicated. I've removed the checking of the return values, but I have them in my real code, so this is not a problem

```
int hFileR = open( sAlarmFileName.c_str(), O_CREAT | O_RDONLY, 
                   S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH );
// hFileR is > 0 for sure, so success 

flock( hFileR, LOCK_EX ) /* the result is > 0 for sure, so success*/ 

// read the file into a string
while( (nRes = read(hFileR, BUFF, MAX_RW_BUFF_SIZE)) > 0 ) // ...

//Write new data to file: reopen/create file - write and truncate mode
int hFileW = open( sAlarmFileName.c_str(), 
                   O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | 
                   S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH );
// hFileW is > 0 for sure, so success

do
{
    int nWrtRes = write( hFileW, 
                        szText + nBytesWritten, nSize - nBytesWritten ); 
    // nWrtRes is always >= 0, so success
    nBytesWritten +=  nWrtRes;
}
while( nSize > nBytesWritten );

close( hFileW );    // this one is successful too

if( flock(hFileR, LOCK_UN) == -1 )
{
    // THIS FAILS and executes _Exit( FAILURE );
}

if( close( hFileR ) < 0 )
{
    // if the previous one do not fail, this one is successful too
}
```

---

Sorry for the long question. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm surprised TinyXML doesn't check the ret-val of that `fseek()` before running off to `ftell()`.

Comment: It's almost certainly a multi-threading issue. Between the two uses of the `FILE *`, some other thread has closed the underlying file descriptor. The most likely cause of this is a double close somewhere else in the code.

Comment: By the way, the most common cause of this hard-to-find bug is code that intentionally calls `close` on another thread's file descriptor as a way to get that other thread to stop. For example, TCP code that has a "read thread" and a "write thread" may idiotically have some other thread call `close` on the descriptor as a way to make the read and write threads fail. Among the many horrible things this causes, if another thread gets the same descriptor just as the write thread is about to write, the write thread may write sensitive data to the wrong connection. Use `shutdown`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some words on the understanding of file descriptors:**

Files are global resources. To handle such, a (process) global indexing is used: Integer values, called file descriptors. If a thread opens a file this opened file is referred by an index. This index is unique to a process (**not** to a thread). If a file is closed, the file descriptor (integer index) is not used any more and could be reused by the process (and any of its threads).

**Example:**

By any thread in a process the 1st call to `open()` might return 3, the 2nd might return 4.

If then 3 is closed, the 3rd call to `open()` may return 3 again.

If the 1st call is done by thread 1, the 2nd by thread 2 and the 3rd by thread 3, it is easy to understand that thread 1 shall not close its file descriptor again, as the value of 3 might already have been recycled and in use by thread 3, which would try to access an invalid file descriptor as it might have been closed by the 2nd (errorous) call to `close()` by thread 1. Ok? ;-)

Try setting up some example code, and inspect/log the integer values returned by calls to `open()` and assigned as file descriptors, to get an impression on how it works.

**Note**:

This also might refer to `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`, the "predefined" file descriptors `0`, `1` and `2`. Under recent Linux closing `stdin` followed by a call to `int fd = open("myfoofile.bar", ...)` might very well return `0` as file descriptor `fd`. Anyhow, either the Kernel or the `glibc` is not able to handle such a `0` as expected. Obscure errors might occur using `lseek(fd, ...)` for example. Try it! ;->>

Comment: The note at the end is wrong. Not only *may* `open` return 0 when stdin is closed; it **must** return 0, since it's the lowest-available file descriptor. In single-threaded programs this is a valid way to replace stdin, though of course it has race conditions that preclude doing it in multi-threaded programs. Neither the kernel nor glibc has any problem using file descriptor 0; they both use it all the time as stdin.

Answer (score 6):

One thing to look for is code that closes the same file descriptor twice.

In a single-threaded program this is a harmless programming mistake, because the second `close()` doesn't do anything except return `EBADF`, and a lot of code doesn't bother to check the `close()` return value anyway. In a multithreaded program, however, the descriptor number of the closed descriptor can be allocated in another thread between the two calls to `close()`, so the second `close()` will close an unrelated socket from another thread. Further reads and writes of the other thread's descriptor will then cause the "bad file descriptor" error.

Comment: @MooingDuck: How do you figure? It seems quite likely that some other piece of code is closing the underlying file descriptor.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The other thread calls close on its own file descriptor. Then this code runs and allocates the very same file descriptor since it's now free. Then the other thread calls close again because it's broken. Then this code runs again and finds its file descriptor closed. As far as the other thread is concerned, everything is fine.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: And this answer even clearly says so.  I'm a bad reader :(

Answer (score 2):

If the application is multi-threaded, it might happen if some thread closed the file, while another still tries to access it.

<sup>(because file descriptors, like address space, are global & common to all threads of a process)</sup>

You could use `strace` to understand what syscalls are done.

Comment: You might want to explain how another thread could close a file descriptor that's local to another thread's functions.

Comment: There's really no such thing as a local file descriptor. They're process-level resources.

Comment: @MooingDuck My answer provides one path for that to happen, but there are others. File descriptors are sometimes explicitly shared among threads, stored in global tables, etc. Mistakes happen.

Comment: Also, file descriptors are just ints (from the process' perspective). An inebriated thread could literally just drunk dial some random ints with close() and ruin other threads local FILE * objects. That's not as likely but that's how I like to imagine what is happening.

Comment: Oh my! "because file descriptors, like address space, are global & common to all threads of a process" I didn't know that.. I thought, they are some kind of "local variables" and I thought that each `open` opens a NEW file descriptor for each thread - an independent FD, which cannot be touched by other threads... So, you mean that all `open` calls in the different threads will return the SAME file descriptors? In that case, I must sync the threads to open the file one by one, right? With a `static mutex` for example? Or I've misunderstood something?

Comment: I just mean that file descriptors, like address space, are common to all the threads of a process. Of course, two different `open`-s (e.g. in two different threads) return a different file descriptor (if no `close` happened).

Comment: @KirilKirov: You don't need to sync the threads with a mutex. You just need to make sure another thread never calls a function on a file descriptor that it isn't supposed to be touching. For example, if a thread calls `close` twice on the same file descriptor, it can wreak havoc on a thread that called `open` or `fopen` in-between those two `close` calls (if it got assigned the now-free file descriptor).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - I'm sure this does not happen. For example, in `case 1` as it's shorter - **each** thread has its own `TiXmlDocument` and calls independently `LoadFile`, where this error appear. I'm sure no other threads could touch this `TiXmlDocument`. I need other ideas, unfortunately :\

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - each thread has its own `open`, its own `close`, its own file descriptor (the `int`, returned from `open`) and other threads cannot access that `int`.. (it seems I've misunderstood your answer at the first time) So, I'd like to hear some other ideas.

Comment: I do recommend **using `strace` to understand what is happening**. (You might write a tiny `awk` script to explore that trace file obtained with `strace`).

Comment: @KirilKirov: This code is the victim, likely not the perpetrator. It can be completely different code that's closing this code's file descriptor by mistake.